# iOS error when using writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, frameworks

This is the error I get when I try and compile my project:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum", referenced from:
  -[AddNewPhotoViewController imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:] in AddNewPhotoViewController.o
```

I get the error when calling `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum`. I suspect the error is to do with not importing the necessary frameworks, but I don't know what to import.

Any help?

---

**EDIT**

Here's my `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum` code:

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    // Access the uncropped image from info dictionary
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [_CameraOutput setImage:image];

    writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:));
}
```

---

**EDIT #2**
I had included the following import in my .m file:

```
#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>
```

Comment: Show your code where you call `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum`.

Comment: In the question that you asked where someone suggested that you use `writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum`, they provided you with a link to [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetsLibrary/writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:metadata:completionBlock:) which tells you which frameworks you need to include

Comment: Does it, pardon me, I obviously didn't look hard enough, I'll take another peek

Comment: Yes @NickBull I did include `#import <AssetsLibrary/AssetsLibrary.h>` as suggested in the documentation :/

Comment: Have you also added the framework to your project (not just `#import`)

Comment: Edit - just seen your posted code for where you are calling it. That is incorrect. See Martin R's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum` is a method of `ALAssetsLibrary`, you must do something like

```
ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];
[library writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum:[image CGImage] orientation:(ALAssetOrientation)[image imageOrientation] completionBlock:your_completion_block];
```

Comment: Thanks martin, though I still needed to include the AssetsLibrary framework, I've done it now :)